# how to integrate tradingview chart using my owndata in angular 5?

Tags: angular

i am using tradingview chart http://tradingview.com using charting library .
so how to set chart using my own data???

i'm using jsapi method to populate chart.but they doesn't work.

https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-examples/tree/master/angular5

above link is demo project with complite run of system data.i only set my xustome data.

Comment: show your code, what you have tried and where you ran into trouble

Comment: here is a tutorial on setting up the charting library with API data, explains the JSAPI and Datafeed integrations https://medium.com/@jonchurch/tradingview-js-api-integration-tutorial-introduction-5e4809d9ef36